# Sort a pair of string using collection

Tags: collections, java

I am a new programmer in java.
I want to sort a pair of string using collection.
Basically i want to sort name and the name has two part, first name and last name.
Now if i take first name in a list and sort it then how i will keep change index of second name while sorting first name.
please help.........

Comment: Create an object with fields for both, then sort on those objects.

Comment: Can we see some code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to sort a name, it would be logical to create a class *Name*, with two fields: *firstName* and *lastName*, a constructor to initialize both fields, and getters so we can test it later on.

```
public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Now, since you want to be able to compare names, you have to make sure *Name* implements the *Comparable* interface. Implementing this interface requires you to override the *campareTo()* method, in which you tell the program how to compare the two objects. Like so:

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Name otherName) {
        if(this.firstName.compareTo(otherName.firstName) == 0) {
            return this.lastName.compareTo(otherName.lastName);
        }
        else {
            return this.firstName.compareTo(otherName.firstName);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens in the *compareTo()* method:
First we check if the first names are equal (*compareTo* returns zero). If that is the case, we sort using the last name. Otherwise, we sort using the first name. For more information about the compareTo method of Strings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Now you can test it out using this test class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Name name = new Name("A", "C");
            Name name1 = new Name("A", "A");
            Name name2 = new Name("Ba", "F");
            Name name3 = new Name("Bb", "A");
            Name name4 = new Name("Ca", "D");
            Name name5 = new Name("Cc", "Z");
            Name name6 = new Name("Cc", "W");


            Name nameArray[] = {name, name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6};
            List<Name> names = new ArrayList<Name>(Arrays.asList(nameArray));

            Collections.sort(names);

            for(Name n : names) {
                System.out.println(n.getFirstName() + " " + n.getLastName());
            }
        }
    }
```

We make a List of Names, and sort it using the *Collections.sort()* method.

I hope this helped you! If you have questions, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

1- Create a dedicated object with two members and implements the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Now you can use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

2- Use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a custom Comparator.

As usual Guava has very nice features. See [Ordering](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of something like what you'll need, though an object oriented solution may be better in some instances. List the strings in an array and compare them one by one in the comparator until they're no longer equal. The arrays will maintain the pair and the comparator will take care of the order.

```
    List<String[]> strings;
    Comparator comparator = new Comparator<String[]>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            //if parameters are invalid, throw them out.
            if(o1 == null || o2 == null || o1.length == 0 || o2.length == 0){
                throw new InvalidParameterException();
            }

            //Compare the two arrays of strings, string by string.
            int length = Math.min(o1.length, o2.length);
            for(int i  = 0; i < length; i++){
                int compare = o1[i].compareTo(o2[i]);
                if(compare != 0){
                    return compare;
                }
            }

            //If the two strings are of different lengths but the same until that point, return the longer string as greater.
            if(o1.length > o2.length){
                return 1;
            }  else if(o2.length > o1.length) {
                return -1;    
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(strings, comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the Comparable interface

```
Class Student implements Comparable{
    private String FirstName;
    private String SecondName;
    // getters and setters
    public int compareTo(Student s){
        return this.getFirstName().compareTo(s.getFirstName());
    } 
}
List<Student> list = new ArrayList();

Collections.sort(list);
```